# How to use System Font in iTextSharp with VB.net

Tags: vb.net, fonts, itext

I'm using Itextsharp to convert text files to PDF documents dynamically using VB.net. However I need to use a system font that is not part of the iTextSharp library. I've seen some code examples using C#. However I'm a newbie in programming and my experience is all in Visual Basic. Can someone help me with writing the code to use a system font?

Comment: Have you tried one of the free online converters? Post the code if your having trouble getting it converted.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Unfortunately, we're here to help you figure out why code that you've written, and you think should work, isn't actually working. Questions that ask for help before any code has been written are off topic here, and subject to closing. Search around on the internet a little for tutorials on using fonts in C#, and try to use the API calls those talk about. Then when you can't get code to work, you can post a question, with code to show you what you're already trying.

Comment: OneFineDay, when you refer to a converter, what do you mean?  Are you saying there are converters to change C# to VB.net?

Comment: Ha, I've just read your bio and I see that you learned to code on a TRS-80 just like I did: http://www.slideshare.net/StartUpsBE/bruno-lowagie-tech-startup-day-2015 (third picture on slide 2). I used my TRS-80 4P to start a first venture at the age of 14 (in 1984).

Comment: I actually had the version before the one you used.  It used a cassette as the "tape" drive (lol - so very low tech even for then!).  But it was a good tool for someone like me who had no experience or knowledge.

Answer (score 6):

Suppose that you want to use Arial regular and you have the file `arial.ttf` in your `C:\windows\fonts` directory, then creating the `Font` object is as easy as this:

```
Dim arial As BaseFont = BaseFont.createFont("c:\windows\fonts\arial.ttf", BaseFont.IDENTITY_H, BaseFont.EMBEDDED)
font = New Font(arial, 16)
```

Using the font is easy too:

```
document.Add(New Paragraph("Hello World, Arial.", font))
```

This is almost a literal translation of the Java and C# examples that can be found in abundance. If this doesn't solve your problem, please show what you've tried and explain why it doesn't work.

**Update:**

You claim that you have a file named `Arial monospaced for SAP.ttf` in the directory `C:\Windows\Fonts\`. I am 99% sure that this is not true. I have searched Google for such a font and I found [a webpage that says](http://scn.sap.com/thread/1885079):

> Go to c:\windows\fonts and [it] should contain arimon__.ttf and arimonbd.ttf

In other words, you need:

```
Dim arial As BaseFont = BaseFont.createFont(
    "c:\windows\fonts\arimon__.ttf", BaseFont.IDENTITY_H, BaseFont.EMBEDDED)
Dim arialbd As BaseFont = BaseFont.createFont(
    "c:\windows\fonts\arimonbd.ttf", BaseFont.IDENTITY_H, BaseFont.EMBEDDED)
```

This is *not* an iText problem. It is a problem of not understanding the difference between a file containing a font program and the name of that font program.

In the comments, you claim that the file is named `Arial monospaced for SAP.ttf`. Allow me to guide you through the basics of Windows Explorer.

You are looking at your font directory like this:

[image]

That view shows your the *names of the fonts*, **NOT** the *name of the font files*. Please select the view icon in the top right corner and change it to view the details. This is what you'll see:

[image]

Now right click on the header of the detailed list and select *Font file names*. This is what you'll see:

[image]

Use the path as shown in this overview and *your code will work.* If it doesn't work post a new question and explain *exactly* what you're doing, so that we can correct you. Not every one has the patience to create screen shots to show you that what you're saying is... inaccurate.

If you don't find `arimon__.ttf` nor `arimonbd.ttf` under `c:\windows\fonts`, the fonts probably aren't there. If they aren't there, your code won't work. Another way to check their presence, is by clicking on **Run** under Windows (in the menu that opens when right-clicking the Start icon) and opening `cmd`. Then do `cd c:\windows\fonts` followed by `dir ari*`. This will show you a list of all the font files that start with `ari`.

Take a look at the following screen shot that shows what happens when I do this on my machine:

[image]

As you can see, there is no `arimon__.ttf` or `arimonbd.ttf` in my `c:\windows\fonts` directory, hence your code would never work on my computer.

Comment: Bruno, thank you.  It will be Monday before I can try it.  But I'll report back and let you know.  This looks like the trick!

Comment: Here's the code I'm going to attempt to use:  <br/>  

`Dim fontpath As String = "C:\Windows\Fonts\"`  <br/>  

`Dim bf As BaseFont = BaseFont.CreateFont(fontpath & "Arial monospaced for SAP.ttf", BaseFont.CP1252, BaseFont.EMBEDDED)` 

 `Dim ffont As New Font(bf, 7)`

Comment: It would really surprise me if you had a font file named `Arial monospaced for SAP.ttf`. Are you sure that file exists? I'll update my answer to show you the error of your ways.

Comment: I'm looking at the system folder (C:\Windows\Fonts) and the file name is called just that.  However if I try to copy and paste it to my desktop or some other place, it pasts as 2 files: "arimon_.ttf" and "arimonbd.ttf".   Needless to say, I got the error that it couldn't find that file name.  So I'm going to try to use one of these others and see what happens.  I'll report back.

Comment: no luck using either of these names.  Any thoughts as to what I should do or use?

Comment: I've reviewed your screen shots and have added the "Font File Name" column as suggested.  As you thought, there is not file name for "Arial Monospaced for SAP".  To complicate matters, I don't see "arimon_.ttf" or "arimonbd.tff" listed either.  However I'm going to attempt to using the code you've suggested:

`Dim arial As BaseFont = BaseFont.createFont(
    "c:\windows\fonts\arimon__.ttf", BaseFont.IDENTITY_H, BaseFont.EMBEDDED)`

`Dim arialbd As BaseFont = BaseFont.createFont(
    "c:\windows\fonts\arimonbd.ttf", BaseFont.IDENTITY_H, BaseFont.EMBEDDED)`

Thanks for the help!

Comment: If you don't find `arimon__.ttf` nor `arimonbd.ttf` under `c:\windows\fonts`, the fonts probably aren't there. If they aren't there, your code won't work. Another way to check their presence, is by clicking on **Run** under Windows (in the menu that opens when right-clicking the Start icon) and opening `cmd`. Then do `cd c:\windows\fonts` followed by `dir ari*`. This will show you a list of all the font files that start with `ari`.

Comment: Here's a fun fact: I've gotten the code to work using the "arimon_.ttf" font.  Unfortunately now it isn't working on the other computers that I've installed the program on.  I've ensured the two fonts are installed.  But now luck.  Is this because "iTextSharp" isn't installed on each individual computer?

Comment: How did you package your application? You need to ship your application with the iTextSharp DLL. Also: how did you install the fonts on the other computers? Does your application have permission to use those fonts? From your comment, it's hard to guess whether this is a problem due to wrong packaging of the app or not finding the fonts.

Comment: You've asked 2 good questions.  The application does have the iTextSharp.dll installed.  However I'm unsure as to how to give permission to use the fonts.  How do I do this?

Comment: How did you do this on your own computer? This is a question about a configuration problem. It's very hard to answer questions like this remotely, without having access to the actual machine.

Comment: I'm not sure if the permission configurations on my computer are different than any of the others (truthfully, I won't know how to change the permissions on a computer).  There is no code in the program that would do this.  I'm simply using the code you listed above that points where to find the fonts.

Comment: Do you see the fonts if you open `cmd` and go to `c:\windows\fonts`? Did you register the iTextSharp DLL? Note that when it works on your machine, you are not facing an iTextSharp problem. You are dealing with a configuration problem. You should search StackOverflow for questions such as "How do I package an application that depends on a third party DLL and external files?" (or post such a question if you can't find an answer.) This typically wouldn't be a question tagged as an iText or iTextSharp question.