# Unable to change font in iTextsharp?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, itext

I am using iTextSharp to generate a table and print it on in a pdf. 
I am trying to change the font but it has zero effect what so ever.

```
  Font tablefont = new Font();
            tablefont=FontFactory.GetFont(FontFactory.HELVETICA, 8,BaseColor.RED) ;     

            table.AddCell("Name :");
            PdfPCell cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Star Diamonds") {Font=tablefont});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are starting a new project, I'd suggest using iText 7 for iTextSharp because we've introduced font inheritance in that version; see [Chapter 1: Introducing the PdfFont class](http://developers.itextpdf.com/content/itext-7-building-blocks/chapter-1-introducing-pdffont-class)

If you insist on using iTextSharp 5.5.9, you should read the old tutorials, and create your `Phrase` like this:

```
BaseFont bfTimes = BaseFont.CreateFont(BaseFont.TIMES_ROMAN, BaseFont.CP1252, false);
Font tablefont = new Font(bfTimes, 8);
PdfPCell cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Star Diamonds", tablefont));
```

Or like this:

```
Font tablefont = new Font(FontFamily.TIMES_ROMAN, 8);
PdfPCell cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Star Diamonds", tablefont));
```

Or like this:

```
Font tablefont = FontFactory.GetFont("Times-Roman", 8);
PdfPCell cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Star Diamonds", tablefont));
```

You will find plenty of old font examples in [chapter 11: Choosing the right font](http://developers.itextpdf.com/examples/itext-action-second-edition/chapter-11) of the iText in Action book. The examples presented on that page are in Java, but if you scroll down, you'll find links to all the corresponding `.cs` files.

There's also an extensive [FAQ section about fonts](http://developers.itextpdf.com/faq/category/fonts), consisting of answers to questions that have been posted on StackOverflow in the past.

Although not an *exact duplicate*, I closed the question by referring to [How to use System Font in iTextSharp with VB.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29997695/how-to-use-system-font-in-itextsharp-with-vb-net)

You are using C#, but the following line is very similar to what you need:

```
document.Add(New Paragraph("Hello World, Arial.", font))
```

The `Paragraph` class is a subclass of the `Phrase` class that you are using. Just like with `Paragraph`, you need to pass the `font` (in your case `tablefont`) as the second parameter of the constructor.

There's a second reason why I refer to [How to use System Font in iTextSharp with VB.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29997695/how-to-use-system-font-in-itextsharp-with-vb-net) : in the answer to that question, you get very detailed information on how to use any font that is available on your machine.

Comment: ITextSharp looks great but,I am working on an existing project which uses iTextSharp. Your answer solved my problem though. 
Please include   the following code in your answer for the sake of completeness. 

`BaseFont bfTimes = BaseFont.CreateFont(BaseFont.TIMES_ROMAN, BaseFont.CP1252, false);
            Font tablefont = new Font(bfTimes, 8, Font.NORMAL);`

Comment: There's really no need to create a `BaseFont` instance if you are using a Standard Type 1 font such as Times-Roman. Also: defining a style (such as `Font.NORMAL`) doesn't really make sense if you use the *font* rather than the *font family*. I know that you found that code snippet on Mike's dotnetting, and although Mike did a great job writing examples, some of the advice he's giving isn't always accurate ;-)